# Generic type array of objects in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Give then following:

```
interface Datum {
    [k: string]: any
}

type Data = Datum[]

const inner = (data: Data) => {
    console.log(data)
};


const outer = (data: Data | Data[]) => {
    inner(data) // expect type error?
};
```

I dont understand how I dont get a `type error` on the `inner function call`. I guess it has something to do with the `generic`. Cant figure out a way of rewriting.

Comment: I think it's because you defined an array here `type Data = Datum[]`

Comment: @JohnMontgomery: I think the OP expects to get an error but isn't.

Comment: @FelixKling Ah, I misread the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Datum` interface is just too broad. It will represent basically any object (ie indexable by a string and the result of the indexing operation is `any`).

Given the object type is soo wide, both `Datum` and `Datum[]` and `Datum[][]` are assignable to an array type, and thus you don't get any error. Make the interface a bit more specific and you get an error. Ex:

```
interface Datum {

    [k: string]: boolean | number | string;
}

type Data = Datum[]

const inner = (data: Data) => {
    console.log(data)
};


const outer = (data: Data | Data[]) => {
    inner(data) // error now
};
```

Or as @PatrickRoberts mentions in comments you can add a `number` index to the interface to make it explicitly incompatible with an array:

```
interface Datum {
    [i: number]: never
    [k: string]: any;
}

type Data = Datum[]

const inner = (data: Data) => {
    console.log(data)
};


const outer = (data: Data | Data[]) => {
    inner(data) // error
};
```

Comment: Could also add `[i: number]: never` to `Datum` instead of modifying the string keyed signature.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts good solution, mind if I add it to the answer ?

Comment: Not at all, that's why I suggested it since you already had the same explanation as I would have given :)

Comment: Thanks - really appreciate that. New it was something to do with that.

Answer (score 2):

The best option would probably be using directly the `object` interface instead of `Datum`:

```
interface Datum {
    [k: string]: any
};
// This is an object interface.

type Data = object[]; // instead of Datum[]


const inner = (data: object[]) => {
    console.log(data)
};
```

Pd: I was looking for a solution for this same issue, used the solution from @titian-cernicova-dragomir which worked nicely. I ended up finding the object interface being used in the `react-csv` library.